# How to remove 'marker' element in bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've made an account options dropdown on my site using bootstrap, it uses your account picture as a button. The problem is for some reason when it's run a ::marker element is created which shows up as a black bullet next to the dropdown. I've pasted my code into a snippet and when you run it you can see the exact same thing happens. My only idea is to use some javascript to remove this element but I figure there must be a better way or something that I'm missing. I've searched the documentation for a little while albeit admittedly not that closely.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img id="acc" alt="Your Profile Picture" class="pfp" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mAJhsrc2jWxXLM1-t503rYNBj128tuqFiQUgSVI2dQ=k-s48"></img>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account settings</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have cover `<li>`tag with `<ul>` tag and add this css:

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <img id="acc" alt="Your Profile Picture" class="pfp" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mAJhsrc2jWxXLM1-t503rYNBj128tuqFiQUgSVI2dQ=k-s48"></img>
    </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account settings</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The marker element resulted from the dropdown item being a `<li>` element of `<ul>` list. If you want to take it out of the list, change it to something else like a  and the "." or marker element should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I was using the "nav-item dropdown" class when I should be using just "dropdown" since this wasn't a part of a navbar.